# ElasticSearch 5.5.0: Finding relevant documents

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch 5.5.0, I was going though “more_like_this” clause but not able to find relevant documents. I have below data in ElasticSearch and “description” field is having huge non-indexed data of size >1 million bytes. Like below I have ten thousand documents. How can I figure out a set of documents which are matching at least 80% with each other:

```
{
    "_index": "school",
    "_type": "book",
    "_id": "1",
    "_source": {
      "title": "How to drive safely",
      "description": "LOTS OF WORDS...The book is written to help readers about giving driving safety guidelines. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. LONG...."
    }
}
```

At the end, I am looking for list of document ID’s which have at least 80% matching contents. Possible expected result containing matching document IDs (any format is fine):

```
[ [1,30, 500, 8000], [2, 40, 199], .... ]
```

Do I need to write batch and compare each document with all others and build output set?

Please help.

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: matching content on what ? All fields or few selected fields ? You want to build somekind of de-dup logic ? I am afraid you have to handle that in code or some logic by iterating on all docs.

Comment: Looking for comparing “description” field of all available 10,000 books against “description” field of each book. Need to find 80% matching books.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [more like this query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) has a parameter called `minimum_should_match`, which can be set to `80%`. However the `max_query_terms` parameter also needs to be taken into account here.

Most importantly, this onls works when you index the contents of those fields.

Also, doing this at query time sounds like a really slow operation. You might want to rethink your strategy here and cluster/group documents on index time (something you need to do yourself as this is a very customised thing to do), so that searching becomes fast.

Comment: Thanks @alr, appreciate your response. I have already applied minimum_should_match to 80%, but since it is extremely big string, matching doesn't seems to be right. For 10,000 documents I think one single machine can handle the load. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @NikhilJoshi -- the answer also mentioned that you need to look at `max_query_terms` -- have you tried increasing that parameter? Keep in mind that `max_query_terms` is relative to the number of _unique_ terms in a document (not the length of the document). (It doesn't so much matter the unindexed size of the data, it matters how many unique terms there are, which, if you're lucky, might be lower than you think.)

Comment: I have provided maxQueryTerms value to 100. Does that mean if document have only matching 75 words, it will be ignored?

Comment: Thanks @alr for providing the directions. I have used combination of minimumShouldMatch, maxQueryTerms and minWordLength to get close to the desired results. Awarding you 50 bounties, really appreciate your help.